# Basic JQuery - sending Ajax request with bind data

Tags: jquery

So i have this :

```
<span><a class="deleteComment" data-bind="'id':1 , 'pointer': 2" href="/delete-comment/@response.getId">delete</a></span>
```

If i also have this javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someurl", 
    type: "post", 
    contentType: "application/json",        
    data: JSON.parse($(this).data("bind")),
    success: function(response){
        ...
    },
    error: function(){ }
});
```

How do i do it so that the "data' in the ajax is just a JSON object?

Right now when i inspect what i send, it isn't JSON - this is super annoying!

Comment: A JSON object has to be surrounded by `{}`.

Comment: Can't you just wrap the string in curly braces and parse as a JSON?

Comment: omg thanks everyone - why is JS such a ridic language that there is a difference between ' and " that is just... doesn't error about????

Comment: There's no difference in Javascript. JSON is a simplified subset of Javascript syntax.

Comment: It's simpler, to make it easier to write parsers for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data-bind` attribute isn't valid JSON. In JSON, an object has to be surrounded by curly braces, and strings and property names have to be quoted with double quotes, not single quotes.

```
<span><a class="deleteComment" data-bind='{"id":1 , "pointer": 2}' href="/delete-comment/@response.getId">delete</a></span>
```

Also, you shouldn't call `JSON.parse()`. When jQuery's `.data()` method notices that the value of the attribute is valid JSON, it automatically parses it.

Since you want the `data:` parameter to be the JSON string, you need to call `JSON.stringify()` to convert the object back to JSON (`$.ajax` converts objects to a URL-encoded string).

Comment: I also needed to call JSON.stringify to make it java-friendly - so the full solution is, as both you and @Serhat MERCAN notice, that I need the quotes right and the brackets present, AND  data: JSON.stringify($(this).data("bind")) -> the stringify is essential for java/scala play framework (and, presumably, other java/scala frameworks()

Comment: (i know you were first, i just thought maybe Serhat, as a newer member, could do with some extra points!)

Comment: I don't have a problem with people choosing other equivalent answers, but his answer is wrong, since he didn't fix the quotes.

Comment: yes, thanks for that - you're right I'll mark you as correct and keep it like that. My mistake, I didn't notice he didn't fix the quotes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you dont use the brackets, it will just string

```
<span><a class="deleteComment" data-bind='{"id":1 , "pointer": 2}' href="/delete-comment/@response.getId">delete</a></span>
```

Comment: Properties in JSON have to be in double quotes, not single quotes.